# How to create a combination of different features and pass them to a random forest classifiers?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, random-forest

My goal is to create a combination of features available (EX: a combination of just 1 feature, just 2, just3 and etc). I achieve this using the `combination` function in python. the problem comes when I pass my combofallfeat to `X = signaldata[i]` and I get an error.
I intend to test out each combination and compare their accuracy:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


# Path to the dataset
file_path = '../input/Data.csv'
#import dataset
signaldata = pd.read_csv(file_path)



comb1 = combinations(['RMSEVM', 'MAXEVM', 'EYEAMP', 
            'EYESNR', 'EYEDELAY', 'EYEWIDTH',
            'ENERGY', 'BPR', 'MEANEIGEN'], 1)
comb2 = combinations(['RMSEVM', 'MAXEVM', 'EYEAMP', 
            'EYESNR', 'EYEDELAY', 'EYEWIDTH',
            'ENERGY', 'BPR', 'MEANEIGEN'], 2)
comb3 = combinations(['RMSEVM', 'MAXEVM', 'EYEAMP', 
            'EYESNR', 'EYEDELAY', 'EYEWIDTH',
            'ENERGY', 'BPR', 'MEANEIGEN'], 3)
comb4 = combinations(['RMSEVM', 'MAXEVM', 'EYEAMP', 
            'EYESNR', 'EYEDELAY', 'EYEWIDTH',
            'ENERGY', 'BPR', 'MEANEIGEN'], 4) 
comb5 = combinations(['RMSEVM', 'MAXEVM', 'EYEAMP', 
            'EYESNR', 'EYEDELAY', 'EYEWIDTH',
            'ENERGY', 'BPR', 'MEANEIGEN'], 5) 
comb6 = combinations(['RMSEVM', 'MAXEVM', 'EYEAMP', 
            'EYESNR', 'EYEDELAY', 'EYEWIDTH',
            'ENERGY', 'BPR', 'MEANEIGEN'], 6)
comb7 = combinations(['RMSEVM', 'MAXEVM', 'EYEAMP', 
            'EYESNR', 'EYEDELAY', 'EYEWIDTH',
            'ENERGY', 'BPR', 'MEANEIGEN'], 7) 
comb8 = combinations(['RMSEVM', 'MAXEVM', 'EYEAMP', 
            'EYESNR', 'EYEDELAY', 'EYEWIDTH',
            'ENERGY', 'BPR', 'MEANEIGEN'], 8) 
comb9 = combinations(['RMSEVM', 'MAXEVM', 'EYEAMP', 
            'EYESNR', 'EYEDELAY', 'EYEWIDTH',
            'ENERGY', 'BPR', 'MEANEIGEN'], 9) 

combofallfeat = list(comb1) + list(comb2) + list(comb3) + list(comb4) + list(comb5) + list(comb6) + list(comb7) + list(comb8) + list(comb9)

#for i in list(combofallfeat): 
#    print (i) 

#set y to be our target of prediction     
y = signaldata.LABEL
#set x to be our features used in training
for i in list(combofallfeat):
    X = signaldata[i]

#split data set into training and testing with %70 for training and %30 for testing
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

#Create a Gaussian Classifier
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)

#Train the model using the training sets y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

#get predictions
    y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)

#print accuracy
    print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

The Error I get:

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: ('RMSEVM',)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-aeda6c0b8228> in <module>
     58 #set x to be our features used in training
     59 for i in list(combofallfeat):
---> 60     X = signaldata[i]
     61 
     62 #split data set into training and testing with %70 for training and %30 for testing

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2978             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2979                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2980             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2981             if is_integer(indexer):
   2982                 indexer = [indexer]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
-> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: ('RMSEVM',)
```

Sample of Dataset

[image]

Comment: The problem is not clear to me, can you provide a input dataframe `signaldata`?

Comment: Dear @Massifox I have added a snapshot of my dataset. My goal is to pass RMSEVM to the random forest and record the accuracy, then repeat the process and pass RMSEVM with MAXEVM and continue the process for all the possible combinations. Please let me know if more information is needed

Comment: Dear @Massifox thank you very much for your contribution to this project your edits helped me move in the right direction.

Comment: Very well! I’m glad to helped you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some considerations:

1. I created fake `signaldata` dataframe to do tests, replace this data with your csv
2. To filter the dataset values ​​by columns you have to use a list of
   strings, before you used a tuple.
3. I created `combofallfeat` more compactly using list comprehension and the `sum()` trick to convert a list of lists into a list
4. In addition to accuracy (tip: don't be satisfied only with accuracy as a metric, try others to validate your model), I added [feature_importances_](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html) to each step, so you can see the predictive contribution of features for each combination
5. I added a `results` list to accumulate the results
6. At the end I order the results for accuracy and print the first 3

Here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

features = ['RMSEVM', 'MAXEVM', 'EYEAMP', 'EYESNR', 'EYEDELAY', 'EYEWIDTH', 'ENERGY', 'BPR', 'MEANEIGEN']

# FAKE INPUT DATA
signaldata = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(10, len(features))), columns=features)
signaldata['LABEL'] = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10, 1))

# Create all combinations list in one line
combofallfeat = sum([list(combinations(features, i)) for i in range(1,10)], [])

y = signaldata.LABEL
results = []

#set x to be our features used in training
for comb_features in list(combofallfeat):
    # Filter data by comb_features
    X = signaldata[list(comb_features)]

    # Train and evaluate your classifier
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)
    accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    row_res = {"features": comb_features, "accuracy": accuracy, "feature_importances_": clf.feature_importances_}

    #print(row_res)

    # Store result
    results.append(row_res)

# Sort result by accuracy
sorted_results = sorted(results, key = lambda i: i['accuracy'], reverse=True)

# Print top 3 results
print(sorted_results[:3])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for going the extra mile and adding feature importance and cleaning up my messy code :'). this was very helpful.

Comment: @mahdi Good :-)